# Setting up Mail (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email using GMail SMTP server from PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

I'm pretty new to mail in PHP, and I am wanting to set up mail().

The problem is, after a few hours of trying to get it working, I simply can not!

I am wanting this to happen:

I want to send emails to the users on my website via my gmail address.

1. I am not sure WHERE i configure SMTP for gmail. Do i edit the settings in php.ini (ssl:smtp.gmail.com; 465)?
2. Is there a way to send emails using the PHP mail() function without the need to use something like pear? I am just wanting to use the mail() function.
3. If that is not possible, is there a way I can send emails to my users via the localhost setup?

I am pretty confused after looking around for answers during the past few hours.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You really, really don't want to use `mail`.  Really.  Especially if you're SMTPing.

Comment: duplicate of this question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page) Please use the solution posted there, it's nice.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to get PHP to send mail using SMTP is via the [`Mail` Pear package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php).

This way you don't have to involve and obese third party libraries like PHPMailer.

---

Here's an example:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$headers = array(
  'From' => "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>",
  'To' => $to="Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>",
  'Subject' => "Hi!"
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
  'host' => "ssl://smtp.gmail.com",
  'port' => 465,
  'auth' => true,
  'username' => "smtp_username",
  'password' => "smtp_password"
));

$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo $mail->getMessage();
}
else {
  echo "mail sent successfully";
}
```

Comment: Do note that while PEAR's Mail package will do the job well, it's really, really old code.  You're going to see plenty of strict notices.  This is OK.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned I didn't want to use it, but I guess its my only option. I downloaded the Pear mail files, but Pear is not installed on my IIS server. I'm a bit stuck, if you could help me?

Comment: @zuc0001, sorry, I'd recommend just using PHPMailer then.